# Rails - Adding Contacts to a Contractor One to Many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm fairly new to rails and I am trying to allow users to add a contact to a contractor. I have set up the one to many association where Conractors has many contacts and contacts belongs to contractor. This is a rails 4 app.

```
class Contractor < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :services
has_many :contacts

accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, allow_destroy: true
```

Where I am getting confused is what i have to do in the Contractor Controller to allow the user to create, edit and show the contact under the contractor (the contractor may or may not yet exist). This is what i have so far in my controller

```
def show
    @contractor = Contractor.find(params[:id])
    @contact = @contractor.contacts.find(params[:contractor_id])
end    
def create
    @contractor = Contractor.create(contractor_params)
    @contact = @contractor.contacts.create!(params[:contractor_id])

        if @contractor.save
            flash[:success] = "New contractor successfully created"
            redirect_to contractor_path(@contractor)
        else render :new    
        end    
end
```

In my view i am showing the contact details using this

```
<td><%= @contact.first_name %></td>
<td><%= @contact.last_name %></td>
```

I'm getting an error of 'Couldn't find Contact without an ID' however i have the resources for both contractors and contacts set in my routes. I have spent a lot of time looking at various answers on here and haven't been able to solve the problem, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
In your controller create action
def create
  @contractor = Contractor.create(contractor_params)
  find_contractor = Contractor.find(:contractor_id => @contractor.id)
  @contact = find_contractor.contacts.create!(contact_params)
  **remaining code here
end

In your show action
def show
  @contractor = Contractor.find(:contractor_id)
  @contacts = @contractor.contacts
end
here you can get many contacts of the same contractor.
```